# How to reveal an element (ex. button) after hovering on a certain element of the site?

Tags: hidden

The problem is I want to make the gray button hidden and get revealed after hovering on a card with hotel pictures.

Currently, I have this site as an example: https://cofffelo.github.io/HotelShop/#

I tried to hide the buttons at their default state by display:none and make it display:block by executing :hover pseudo-index, but because it was hidden from the start, there was nothing to hover, and because I'm kind of a newbie, I ran out of ideas.

The code I tried to add:

```
.cardbutton{
    display: none;  
}

.cardbutton:hover{
    transform: translateY(30px);
    display: block;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [transition delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay)

```
.cardbutton:after {
    opacity: 0;
    content: "";
}
.cardbutton:hover:after { 
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity  0s linear 1.5s;
    content: "content text here";
}
```